# Fluter: Creating a new textfile and writing to it

Tags: flutter, dart

I do not know how to accomplish in my desktop App to write to a new created file.

In my ToDo example app I am able to write to a file and save it.

```
 void _save() {
    _addItem(
      controllerTitle.value.text,
      controllerText.value.text,
    );
    controllerTitle.clear();
    controllerText.clear();
  }

  _addItem(
    String title,
    String text,
  ) {
    setState(() {
      final item = TodoItem(title: title, text: text);
      list.items.add(item);
      _saveToStorage();
    });
  }

  _saveToStorage() {
    storage.setItem('todo', list.toJSONEncodable());
  }

  _clearStorage() async {
    await storage.clear();

    setState(() {
      list.items = storage.getItem('todo') ?? [];
    });
  }
```

The path and file name is hard coded.

```
  final LocalStorage storage = LocalStorage('Todos/todo.json');
```

I am able to create a new file with different name in the same path.

```
  Future<void> _createFileFolderFirstStart() async {
    rootPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create the first directory if not exists
    Directory sampleFolder = Directory('${rootPath!.path}/Todos');
    if (!sampleFolder.existsSync()) {
      sampleFolder.createSync();
    }

    // Create the first file if not exists
    File sampleFile = File('${sampleFolder.path}/todo.json');
    if (!sampleFile.existsSync()) {
      sampleFolder.createSync();
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _createNewFile() async {
    rootPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create the  directory if not exists
    Directory sampleFolder = Directory('${rootPath!.path}/Todos');

    // Create the other files if not exists
    File sampleFile =
        File('${sampleFolder.path}/${_filenameController.text}.json');
    if (!sampleFile.existsSync()) {
      sampleFile.createSync();
    }

    setState(() {});
  }
```

Only i do not know how i can accomplish that the app writes to the new file after i created it.

Follows the complete code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:localstorage/localstorage.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class TodoItem {
  String title;
  String text;

  TodoItem({required this.title, required this.text});

  toJSONEncodable() {
    Map<String, dynamic> m = {};

    m['title'] = title;
    m['text'] = text;

    return m;
  }
}

class TodoList {
  List<TodoItem> items = [];

  toJSONEncodable() {
    return items.map((item) {
      return item.toJSONEncodable();
    }).toList();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final TodoList list = TodoList();

  final LocalStorage storage = LocalStorage('Todos/todo.json');

  TextEditingController controllerTitle = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerText = TextEditingController();
  final _filenameController = TextEditingController();

  Directory? rootPath;
  String? filePath;
  String? dirPath;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _createFileFolderFirstStart();
    super.initState();
  }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------LOCALSTORAGE Json FUNCTIONS--------------------
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------

  void _save() {
    _addItem(
      controllerTitle.value.text,
      controllerText.value.text,
    );
    controllerTitle.clear();
    controllerText.clear();
  }

  _addItem(
    String title,
    String text,
  ) {
    setState(() {
      final item = TodoItem(title: title, text: text);
      list.items.add(item);
      _saveToStorage();
    });
  }

  _saveToStorage() {
    storage.setItem('todo', list.toJSONEncodable());
  }

  _clearStorage() async {
    await storage.clear();

    setState(() {
      list.items = storage.getItem('todo') ?? [];
    });
  }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // --------Create & Rename File Functions--------------------------
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------

  Future<void> _createFileFolderFirstStart() async {
    rootPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create the first directory if not exists
    Directory sampleFolder = Directory('${rootPath!.path}/Todos');
    if (!sampleFolder.existsSync()) {
      sampleFolder.createSync();
    }

    // Create the first file if not exists
    File sampleFile = File('${sampleFolder.path}/todo.json');
    if (!sampleFile.existsSync()) {
      sampleFolder.createSync();
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _createNewFile() async {
    rootPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create the  directory if not exists
    Directory sampleFolder = Directory('${rootPath!.path}/Todos');

    // Create the other files if not exists
    File sampleFile =
        File('${sampleFolder.path}/${_filenameController.text}.json');
    if (!sampleFile.existsSync()) {
      sampleFile.createSync();
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(children: [
          TextField(
            controller: controllerTitle,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Title',
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: controllerText,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Text',
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
                onPressed: _save,
                tooltip: 'Save',
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                onPressed: _clearStorage,
                tooltip: 'Clear storage',
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 200.0,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _filenameController,
                  decoration:
                      const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter New File Name'),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  [
                    await _createNewFile(),
                    _filenameController.clear(),
                  ];
                },
                child: const Text('Create New File'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution for my problem.
I do not know if this is the correct way to do, but it works.
I used Get_storage package to store the name of the new file and i called it when it is necessary for example, writing to the new created file.

Follows the complete code

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:localstorage/localstorage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';



void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Get Storage',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------LOCALSTORAGE TodoItem Class--------------------
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
class TodoItem {
  String title;
  String text;

  TodoItem({required this.title, required this.text});

  toJSONEncodable() {
    Map<String, dynamic> m = {};

    m['title'] = title;
    m['text'] = text;

    return m;
  }
}

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------LOCALSTORAGE TodoList Class--------------------
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
class TodoList {
  List<TodoItem> items = [];

  toJSONEncodable() {
    return items.map((item) {
      return item.toJSONEncodable();
    }).toList();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController controllerTitle = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerText = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController fileNameController = TextEditingController();

  static GetStorage getfileName = GetStorage();
  final TodoList list = TodoList();
  late LocalStorage storage;

  Directory? rootPath;
  String? filePath;
  String? dirPath;

  @override
  void initState() {
    createFolderFirstStart();
    super.initState();
  }

  clearTextInput() {
    fileNameController.clear();
  }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------LOCALSTORAGE Json FUNCTIONS--------------------
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------

  void _save() {
    _addItem(
      controllerTitle.value.text,
      controllerText.value.text,
    );
    controllerTitle.clear();
    controllerText.clear();
  }

   void _addItem(
    String title,
    String text,
  ) {
    setState(() {
      final item = TodoItem(title: title, text: text);
      list.items.add(item);
      _saveToStorage();
    });
  }

    void _saveToStorage() {
    storage.setItem('todo', list.toJSONEncodable());
  }

    void _clearStorage() async {
    await storage.clear();

    setState(() {
      list.items = storage.getItem('todo') ?? [];
    });
  }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // --------Create & Rename File Functions--------------------------
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------

  Future<void> createFolderFirstStart() async {
    rootPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create the first directory if not exists
    Directory sampleFolder = Directory('${rootPath!.path}/Todos');
    if (!sampleFolder.existsSync()) {
      sampleFolder.createSync();
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> createNewFile() async {
    rootPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create the  directory if not exists
    Directory sampleFolder = Directory('${rootPath!.path}/Todos');

    // Create the other files if not exists

    File('${sampleFolder.path}/${getfileName.read('file_name')}.json');
    storage = LocalStorage('Todos/${getfileName.read('file_name')}.json');
    _clearStorage();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: controllerTitle,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Title',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: controllerText,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Text',
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
                  onPressed: _save,
                  tooltip: 'Save',
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                  onPressed: _clearStorage,
                  tooltip: 'Clear storage',
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 20,
              thickness: 2,
              indent: 20,
              endIndent: 0,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            const Text(
              'FILE NAME:',
            ),
            Text(
              (getfileName.read('file_name') ?? ' n/a'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 250.0,
              child: TextField(
                controller: fileNameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Give New File Name',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    getfileName.write('file_name', fileNameController.text);
                    createNewFile();
                    clearTextInput();
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.save,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    [clearTextInput()];
                    setState(() {
                      getfileName.remove('file_name');
                      clearTextInput;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```